# Convert dataframe to json format

Tags: python, json, pandas

I am trying to convert a dataframe into json in order to upload to Google sheet with API. I do not have an error but the code below gives an empty json data. Any help would be appreciate.

Dataframe `BTCJPY` sample:

```
                            close          high           low    market_cap          open        volume  Volatility
timestamp                                                                                                          
2019-04-06 23:59:05  5.653111e+05  5.816236e+05  5.577590e+05  9.967346e+12  5.627387e+05  1.891492e+12         NaN
2019-04-07 23:59:05  5.807896e+05  5.848436e+05  5.642018e+05  1.024129e+13  5.655849e+05  1.860643e+12         NaN
2019-04-08 23:59:09  5.896111e+05  5.928508e+05  5.738326e+05  1.039793e+13  5.795867e+05  1.912040e+12    0.008621
2019-04-09 23:59:06  5.783351e+05  5.877751e+05  5.741640e+05  1.020004e+13  5.877751e+05  1.635807e+12    0.024263
2019-04-10 23:59:05  5.910173e+05  6.017952e+05  5.764577e+05  1.042481e+13  5.776479e+05  1.720986e+12    0.029029
2019-04-11 23:59:04  5.653437e+05  5.976868e+05  5.600758e+05  9.973065e+12  5.944335e+05  1.848087e+12    0.046222
```

My code:

```
BTCJPY = pd.DataFrame.from_records(used_list)
BTCJPY['timestamp'] = pd.to_datetime(BTCJPY['timestamp'])
BTCJPY['Volatility'] = BTCJPY['close'].pct_change().dropna().rolling(2).std().dropna()
BTCJPY = BTCJPY.set_index('timestamp')
BTCJPY = BTCJPY.to_json()
```

Comment: try to print BTCJPY before to_json to check BTCJPY contains data or not

Comment: The sample above is `print(BTCJPY)`

Comment: I actually tried on sample data and it is working

Comment: It works, provided `timestamp` is not the index...